# Force the changing of browser encoding using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, encoding

I've got some content on the page which is in another language other than English, e.g. Russian, Polish, etc.

So when someone has their browser encoding set to ISO-8859-1 or any other language, it will just be trash on my screen. So is there a way for me to force the changing of browser encoding using JavaScript so even when they change it to a Western Encoding, that it will still be able to show the content correctly?

Comment: Cannot you set the meta-data in the HTML header?

Comment: Since this does not have a good answer yet: just set your encoding as UTF-8 or some other Unicode charset. If the user forces ISO-8859-1 deliberately, it is going to corrupt - and that's on them. You can't cater for users who set things wrong deliberately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use META CHAR manipulation by using javascript or php.  But HTTP Header has higher priority than META charset.  if  you should have access right to web server you may solve by adding http headers for different languages

Comment: Yeah, so then is there a way for me to use PHP to change the HTTP header? thanks

Comment: Please check php header function... http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php   Also on server side you may check apache (or web server you use) config to set up http headers

Comment: if you access to web server, in etc/apache2/conf.d/charset
add these lines. change iso code to suit your needs

         #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
         AddDefaultCharset iso-8859-1